# auto generating surrogates shows an error to many rows to insert

Tags: mysql, sql-server, subquery, bulkinsert

I want to populate my table by getting values from one table to another?
I have Two tables 1st one is`SURROGATE` which have two columns `ID , NAME` 2nd Table named as `NAMES`. So I want to get only names from 2nd table and want to populate into 1st table. Limitation  is that i don't want to declare **ID** column as **PK** neither as Identity  column. that's mean I have to generate surrogate/sequence for **ID** column by myself. For this what i have done is below here

```
    declare @cout  int
declare @i  int
set @i=1
set @cout = (select COUNT(abc) from crm.dbo.NAMES)
while(@i<=@cout)
Begin
insert into crm.dbo.SURROGATE(ID,NAME)values
((select coalesce(max(ID), 0)+1 from crm.dbo.SURROGATE),

(select  top (@i) abc from crm.dbo.NAMES  ))
 set @i= @i+1
 end
```

when I execute this query, on first iteration it  gives one row which successfully inserted to 1st table but on 2nd iteration it returns top 2 rows but i want only 2nd one, 2nd issue is that on 2nd iteration it select 2 rows on insertion it gives an error to many rows want to insert

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the second iteraition `@i = 2` so you got `TOP 2` rows to insert. Better use [ROW_NUMBER](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql) to create some `id`:

```
DECLARE @max_sur int

SELECT @max_sur = max(ID)
FROM crm.dbo.SURROGATE

INSERT INTO crm.dbo.SURROGATE 
SELECT  COALESCE(@max_sur,0) + ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) as new_id,
        abc 
FROM crm.dbo.NAMES
```

Comment: thanks sir its working properly
**ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) as new_id** but unable to understand from  here what this line does

Comment: @Ahmad You can read about `ROW_NUMBER` on MSDN (I left a link in my answer). Basicaly, this function returns the sequential number of a row within some partition, starting at 1. We dont use partition here. `ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)` means to order resultset _randomly_. Yo can use .`ORDER BY some_column` if you want.

Comment: My pleasure! :-)